# Server response differs on random which make Json.Parse fail

Tags: javascript, c#, json, typescript, server

I got a really weird problem that drives me crazy. It started that i noticed that my Json.Parse failed at sometimes. It looks like this

```
const Info = JSON.parse(response);
this.onInfoUpdate(Info.InfoConfig[0]);
```

and the two different responses i get are

```
"{\"InfoConfig\":[{\"InfoId\":1,\"InfoName\":\"Derp\",\"Pid\":0,\"StartDate\":\"2018-10-31T00:00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"2018-11-10T00:00:00\",\"InclusiveFilters\":null,\"ExlusiveFilters\":null,\"Type\":0}],\"InfoIds\":["1"],\"Guid\":\"2#myman\"}"
```

This one it cant parse to an Json object. i cant figure out why it sometimes decide to remove the \ and also no "" around the whole array

```
{"InfoConfig":[{"InfoId":1,"InfoName":"Derp","Pid":0,"StartDate":"2018-10-31T00:00:00","EndDate":"2018-11-10T00:00:00","InclusiveFilters":null,"ExlusiveFilters":null,"Type":0}],"InfoIds":["1"],"Guid":"2#myman"}
```

This one works fine and the JSON.parse converts it ot an Json object. But sometimes i get the response

This is the part that sends the data to the frontend

```
case HiveMessageType.PlayerInfo:
                var playerNotification = (PlayerInfoNotificationModel)message;
                var InfoIds = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerNotification.InfoIds);
                var serializedListWithInfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerNotification);
                SignalRClient.SendAsync("RegisterUserToMultipleGroups", playerNotification.Guid, InfoIds, serializedListWithInfo);
                break;
```

Comment: what the code on the backend side?

Comment: @maxs87 edited in the part which sends it

Comment: i am not sure about signalR, but i would test SendAsync without SerializeObject, it seems strange to me that this method doesnt do serialization by default. Also it would be interesting to look on the whole switch case structure - there should be logical explanation why u have different behavior in different cases. Maybe u handle different "case" in different way?

Comment: @maxs87 that did not fix it either :/ the cast structure is because it is a function which recieves messages that it then broadcasts either to all users or just one specific.

Comment: It looks like the first case is getting double-serialized.  Might you be serializing something that is already serialized earlier in the process?  Also note that some frameworks are designed to handle serialization for you, so if you are serializing on top of that, you will end up with the backslashes you see.

Answer (score 0):

The first response is a plain string while the second response is a standard javascript object.

Please wrap `JSON.parse` in try-catch block to prevent parsing exceptions from crashing your app.

Wrapping your variable in `JSON.stringify` will convert the variable data to string if it isn't one already.

```
var Info;
try {
  Info = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
} catch(e) {
  // Suppress the exception
  Info = response
}

// Use variable `Info` for further processing.
```

Comment: I tried it but then it fails everytime. And after more investigation it seems like it is the second response that it is able to parse and not the first

Comment: Did you try the solution that I have posted?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a switch case on HiveMessageType.PlayerInfo. Have you checked that you're not simply going into the wrong switch case when it is not working, and the code in that switch block is just not updated to work?

Seems weird that you get different outputs if you use the same input data and code every time.